# Arrow keys trigger "pause" twice in Windows batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file

try this in an otherwise empty .bat file:

```
@echo off
echo Try space and arrow-down
pause
echo 1
pause
echo 2
pause
echo 3
pause
echo 4
pause
echo 5
```

Why does any of the arrow keys trigger two consecutive pauses, while a space or a letter only triggers one?

Thanks!
bers

Comment: Good question, function keys/home/insert do the same too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect pause is simply a call to [_getch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which blocks until it reads a single character of input, but which has the caveat "When reading a function key or an arrow key, each function must be called twice; the first call returns 0 or 0xE0, and the second call returns the actual key code."

Answer (score 4):

You can work around this problem:

```
PAUSE>NUL|SET /P =optional text
```

With thanks to http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2726

Comment: The actual code to workaround the problem but preserve all other behavior (in English) is `pause>nul|set/p=Press any key to continue . . .&echo(`. The echo( is needed to move the cursor to the next line.